# translate "Please enter the same value again"

Tags: localisation, magento2.4, js-translation

I am trying to change the validation message `Please enter the same value again` for password field using translate csv.but it's not translate on the frontend.

Can any one please guide here what's wrong with this.

I am using `magento 2.4`

Comment: Hey, can you elaborate? Print the field you want to translate, tell where the .csv is, if it is a theme or some other place, something that can tell more of what you tried so we can help easily. :D

Comment: this is for the password field on create account.and i am using theme locale `i18n` en_US.csv

Comment: I'll assume you're editing luma theme, so in your csv you should have "Please enter the same value again.","Some Other text". Make sure you're looking at en_US page, other translations work? Like if you want to translate the labels. Try to run "rm -Rf var/view_preprocessed/* var/*cache/* pub/static/frontend/*
php bin/magento setup:static-content:deploy
php bin/magento cache:flush" just in case it didn't update.

Comment: Yes everthing is working fine except this message.This bug is already raised by someone on github [link](https://github.com/magento/magento2/issues/5956).they said alredy resolved on previous version but still getting

Comment: Interesting, didn't expect that, it does not look like it was resolved, anyway this is not the best solution but you can or remove that warning or edit it in the file it's been called instead of doing a translation, but if you change it directly you might stumble in the same problem if you want to have other languages

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Maybe you've missed the dot? Place the following in `app/design/%vendor%/%theme%/i18n/en_US.csv`

```
"Please enter the same value again.","Please enter the same value again."
```

If it's a *Javascript* translation don't forget to remove:

`pub/static/frontend/%vendor%/%theme%/en_US/js-translation.json`

Also make sure to run:

```
php bin/magento cache:clean
```

If that didn't work: You may have to clean browsers **Local Storage** in addition to Magento internal caches.